# Find the next occurence of lines with matching prefix

Tags: search, regular-expressions

I've got a file that looks roughly like this:

```
prefix.thing,11,12
prefix.something,10,20
prefix.something,30,40
prefix.somethingElse,10,20
prefix.anotherThing,1,2
prefix.anotherThing,3,4
```

assuming my point is at the beginning of the file, how can I find the first pair of lines that match up to the first comma on each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd> to begin a regexp search

Search for `^\(.*?,\).*^J\1`

Note that to insert the `^J` you wont actually type <kbd>^</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>. ^J is the representation of a newline character, you insert this hard new line by typing <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd>

So you are searching for: 
anything not a comma, 
followed by a comma, 
followed by anything to the end of the line, 
followed by a new line, 
followed by the first matched thing.

---

You could turn it into a command like so:

```lisp
(defun find-next-matching-prefix-lines ()
  "Move forward to the next pair of lines that match up to the first comma on each line."
  (interactive)
  (if (re-search-forward "^\\(.*?,\\).*\n\\1" (point-max) t 1)
      (goto-char (line-beginning-position))
    (message "no more matches found!")))
```

Comment: His question sounds unclear to me. Does he need to search for `prefix\.\w+,`?

Comment: I think the word prefix in the text is just an example, not a hard requirment, I think he does actually want "the first pair of lines that match up to the first comma on each line." as he stated.

Comment: that's correct, I'm not looking for a match on the literal "prefix.", the prefix is arbitrary.

Comment: Ah alright. You can also use the non-greedy operator `?` here.. works the same way: `^\(.*?,\).*^J\1`

Comment: Be careful, `[^,]` also matches a newline.

Comment: @politza, thank you, I've updated the regexp to account for that

Answer (score 1):

You can type:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `isearch-forward-regexp` <kbd>RET</kbd> `^\\(.\*\\),.\*` <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> `\1,`

The cryptic characters in the middle form a **regular expression** (or regexp), it is a pattern language that you use to describe what you would like to match. The <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> part inserts a newline character.

Effectively, the regexp specifies:

- `^` It should start at the beginning of a line.
- `\\(.*\\)` It should match anything, and capture the matched string in a *group* (group 1)
- `,` Match an explicit comma
- <kbd>C-q C-j</kbd> This inserts a newline character in the regexp that matches the end of a line
- `\1` This should match the same as group 1 matched.
- `,` Another explicit comma.